# Google is asking for more permissions than my chrome manifest asks for

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When installing my new extension, google is saying it requires permission to **read and change all your data on websites you visit**. Here is my manifest.

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches":        ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "include_globs":  ["http://www.google.*/*", "https://www.google.*/*"],
      "css": ["src/style.css"],
      "js": ["lib/jquery.min.js", "src/script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "logos/*.png",
    "logos/*.gif",
    "logos/*.jpg",
    "src/options.html"
  ],
  "options_page": "src/options.html",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Is this google's poorly worded way of saying it can change the HTML, CSS, and Javascript? Because this makes it sound like its giving the extension access to my personal data on sites. The only permission I even ask for is for local storage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is something you can't avoid when using `"matches":        ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]` regardless of what is inside `include_globs`

Comment: Yeah looking at some of my other extensions, this is the case for lots of minor ones. I think it is a matter of unfortunate wording. Although I guess theoretically it would give the extension access to the user's information on those sites via accessing the DOM.

Comment: If an extension can inject JS into a site, the extension can access any and all data on those sites the user can.